# Reset function on game not working

Tags: jquery, reset

I've been making a simple tile match game using Jquery and everything is okay except after the game is completed it doesn't reset correctly after clicking the modal box) and you can no longer click the divs to play again.

To see the game and code please go to http://codepen.io/acnorrisuk/pen/JdoGvP/
I have console.logged the array of values so you can cheat your way through the game to see what happens when it resets.

The reset function is below:

```
function newBoard() {
    // reset variables
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    temp_values.length = 0;
    tile_values.shuffle();
    tile1 = '';
    tile2 = '';
    $("#board").empty();
    $(".tile").removeClass("transform");
    $("#score").html("<p>Pairs Found: " + 0 + "</p>");
    // gives each div a unique tile number and inserts images
    for (var i = 0; i < tile_values.length; i++) {
        $("#board").append("<div class='flip-container flip'>\
                <div class='tile flipper' id='" + i + "'>\
                    <div class='front'></div>\
                    <div class='back'><img src='" +
            tile_values[i] + "'>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are removing all the tile elements (the ones with the "tile" class) when you create a new board. Those tile elements had the click-handler bound to them, but the newly added tile elements do not have a click handler bound to them.

You could move the code that binds the click-handler so it is inside the `newBoard()` function (after the tile elements are added to the board), but a better way is to use event delegation. With event delegation you can bind the click handler to the `#board` element, which does not get removed and re-added. But the handler will still get called for the tile elements.

Just change this:

```
$(".tile").on("click", function () {
```

To this;

```
$("#board").on("click", '.tile', function () {
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo7mwhx9/)

Note: In the jsfiddle I commented-out the call to shuffle the tiles so it is easier to complete the game.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are appending `.tile` to `#board` in your `newBoard` function, you need to [delegate the click event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
// check if tiles match using a temporary array
$("#board").on("click", '.tile', function () { 
    ... 
});
```

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyPyM)**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdNpGK.

The problem was that you were adding the onClick function to only the first set of cards. When you reset the board, you removed all the old cards, added new ones, but never set the on click function again. Rather than an anonymous function in the onClick event, it now adds the appropriate on click function every time reset is called.

```
function newBoard() {
    ...

    $(".tile").on("click", onClick);
}



function onClick() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(document).on("click",".tile",function () {...});`

http://jsfiddle.net/cnmzxL0a/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all your responses.
 The issue has now been resolved by using:

$("#board").on("click", '.tile', function () {
:)